# Show the week dates in UITableView

Tags: iphone, calendar

In my app i want to show the week's dates in UITableView. I am trying the below code but it is repeating the same date in all rows. Actually what i want to show is the calendar dates in UITableView but week vise.Below is code  i am trying. Hope i made my point clear, if any doubt please ask.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

if(tableView == self.mWeekTable)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [self.mLocationTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDate *dateForCell = [self dateWithDayInterval:indexPath.row sinceDate:firstDayInYear];
   // NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    //NSDate *dateForCell = [self nextDayFromDate:date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-EEEE"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dateForCell];
    cell.textLabel.text = stringFromDate;
}
}

- (NSDate *)firstDayInYear:(NSInteger)year {
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
firstDayInYear = [fmt dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/01/%d", year]];
return firstDayInYear;
  }

  - (NSDate *)dateWithDayInterval:(NSInteger)dayInterval sinceDate:(NSDate *)referenceDate {
static NSInteger SECONDS_PER_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;
return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:dayInterval * SECONDS_PER_DAY sinceDate:referenceDate];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the indexPath.row value to date, it will display new date on each cell.

```
NSMutableArray *dayCollectionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd"];

for (int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
     NSDate *nextDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(i*24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSString *day=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDay];
    [dayCollectionArray addObject:day];

    NSLog(@"day=%d ==  =%@",i,day);

}
```

inside cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

cell.textLable.text=[dayCollectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

inside the loop you can find taday's day and next 6 days,
calculate all day and add to NSMutableArray than you can simply display whole week in a TableView.

Comment: that's ok but i want Tue 18, Wed 19 like this.

Comment: Here is the date formatter guide: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @avi problem is this the condition you put is integer so it is showing only integer value EEEE is for week days name but it is showing 0 1 2 3 4 5 6.

Comment: @avi this is wrong, the solution will be to increment here NSDate *dateForCell = [self dateWithDayInterval:indexPath.row sinceDate:firstDayInYear];

Comment: @avi it is working but just last thing that how can i change the next week by button action and other thing is that it should show the all days of week but it is starting from today to next 7 days.

Comment: @ios7 first object of array always contain today's date, so don't worry, user always get today's date on top than next six day.

Comment: if you want to display week starting from monday/sunday than need to find current date than previous days and next days of week, by using that code you can find any day before and after date, 
in the simple word i is the number of day, if you want to calculate tomorrow's date than i=1, and  if you want to calculate yesterday's date than i=-1.

Comment: @avi that is what i am saying man, week should start from sun then to end of week but it is starting from today.

Answer (score 0):

This is new way that i think it could be accomplished

```
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setDay:16];
    [comps setMonth:6];
    [comps setYear:2013];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MM"];
    NSString *day = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    [comps release];
    [gregorian release];

    NSLog(@"Weekday : %@", day);
```

Comment: This will be printing the days like you want Tue 13 or Wed 19

Comment: @avi has also given same answer

Comment: @avi that is what i am saying format is %d so it will print integer value not string

Comment: this is wrong, the solution will be to increment here NSDate *dateForCell = [self dateWithDayInterval:indexPath.row sinceDate:firstDayInYear];

Comment: check the new edited code, but you have to modify it according to your needs

Comment: date is not static my friend.

Comment: I didn't thought of a static data you can make a separate function with this code and can make a call to that function with the data that is going to change

Comment: [comps setDay:day];
[comps setMonth:month];
[comps setYear:year];

Comment: @ios7:) try that code it will work, i have tested the code, and giving same output like you want.

Comment: that is ok but it is repeating the same date, i am posting the edited code.

Comment: can you post the whole function here?